# A dubious duplicate

Tags: discussion

The following question

[Is the definition of the meter arbitrary?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/294243/26969)

was marked as a duplicate of [Is the second defined arbitrarily?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178660/26969) - which is itself a duplicate of 
[How is a second measured? And why is it measured that way?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73766/26969). None of these questions, or their associated answers, get to the heart of the closed question.

One could close the question for "lack of effort" - but it does explore an interesting aspect of physics, namely the work done to get "truly fundamental" definitions of the SI units.

Closing it with reference to a closed question that itself doesn't address the question is sloppy.

I wanted to calibrate my thought process. What do others think? I don't think "lack of effort when formulating the question" deserves "lack of effort when closing the question" - unless we make "lack of effort" a valid (and distinct) close reason.

Comment: FWIW, I agree with you here, but note that we do have the option to fill in our own close reason and many do use the 'low effort' as the reason.

Comment: And OP could have answered their own question by continuing to read, rather than running off, but that's another thing here

Comment: @KyleKanos - that gets to the "low effort" part...

Comment: My comment was in reference to the 'and distinct' part; we somewhat technically have such a close reason succeed it is fairly common

Comment: Frankly, I don't see the value in repeating the same argument over and over just because the setting has changed slightly. Are we going to allow similar questions when ℏ, e, N_A and k_B are also fixed? As far as I'm concerned this is a duplicate, and I don't think answering this question's eternal re-spawns helps. I voted to close in the understanding that it's only my one vote, but obviously a quorum agrees the question should be closed. If a bigger quorum says reopen (without turning this into a tug of war) then that's that.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - the point I was making is that unless you know the answer, even if you came across the title of the duplicate question you would not know it was a dupe. Even searching for `299792458` doesn't get you to a real duplicate (which the one marked clearly was not). But I was looking to vent - not to start a tug of war.